# Software to edit Mondrian Schemas?

Tags: windows, business-intelligence

I am using the Pentaho community version and a I find lot of problems with the Pentaho Workbech Editor. I see in [GitHub](https://github.com/pentaho/mondrian/tree/master/workbench) that the community tool has not been updated in the last two years. I expect no support as Pentaho is willing to push their enterprise version.

I would like to know if there is a third party tool to edit Mondrian schemas. At this point, apart from the community version I have three alternatives:

- Paying for the enterprise verion? How much would it cost?
- Using any third part tool to edit schemas?
- editing schemas with a plain old text editor? Has anyone tried to work this way?  Do Mondrian give clear messages if I mistakenly create a wrong schema?

Update: Mondrian 4 [introduced](https://github.com/pentaho/mondrian/blob/4.2/RELEASE.txt) a new incompatible XML schema. Mondrian 4 still can work with the old format but with some limitations. The official documentation literally says:

> Schema workbench is obsolete and has been removed. Pentaho hopes to
>   build a replacement, but no firm plans exist at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at Phase which initially only supports Mondrian 3.

(Mondrian 4 is still not production ready. But don't worry about this because it will read a 3 schema and write out a converted 4 schema automatically. so upgrading is simple.)

https://github.com/rpbouman/phase

It's also in the marketplace:

http://www.pentaho.com/marketplace/

Phase is nice because it encourages you to build the schema in a model driven way rather than necessarily in the way the XML forces you to!

Also; The Enterprise version does not have any specific additional schema editor that I'm aware of.

Comment: Seems to work really good. Integrated with pentaho in the tools menu and user friendly.